# pasar variable de nodejs a javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

en el archivo main tengo todo lo que ejecuta al servidor

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/www/"));

app.listen(300,function(){
    console.log("true")
})
```

pero quisiera enviarles variables al cliente, Pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: favor considera reformular tú pregunta

Comment: Si consultas la [documentacion](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res) de express, te percataras que existe un objeto de tipo Response, que te ayuda a enviar datos hacia el front

Comment: tengo curiosidad de saber cual es la necesidad de enviar variables al cliente, el cliente puede pedir datos al servidor y el servidor envía lo que que pidió, no veo la necesidad de enviarle variables,

Answer (score 0):

según entiendo podes enviar información al cliente de dos maneras al menos.
Una es creando rutas para que funcione como una api y podes devolver un objeto Json, la otra es usando un motor de plantillas.
Te dejo dos links uno de la documentación de express donde podes ver como crear rutas y la segunda de stackoverflow en ingles donde dan un ejemplo claro de como usar plantillas y enviar variables para usarlas en el template.

[Documentación express crear rutas](https://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html)

[Enviar variables desde el servidor al cliente usando plantillas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955697/variables-between-node-js-server-and-client)

Espero te sea útil!